# Is it OK to write with overlapped i/o from multiple threads and not using an event in the OVERLPAPPED structure?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, overlapped-io

I use `overlapped i/o` in a windows program. I use one pipe from multiple threads and write to it.

In this a special case the threads should only continue when the complete information is written to the pipe. In other words: When `GetOverlappedResult` returns with the last parameter (`bWait`)set to `TRUE` returns.

My `OVERLAPPED` structure doesn't use an event, so hEvent  is NULL.

Question: Is this a problem or has this performance issues when I don't use a hEvent?

Reason why I ask is the documentation that says:

> If the hEvent member of the OVERLAPPED structure is NULL, the system
> uses the state of the hFile handle to signal when the operation has
> been completed. Use of file, named pipe, or communications-device
> handles for this purpose is discouraged. It is safer to use an event
> object because of the confusion that can occur when multiple
> simultaneous overlapped operations are performed on the same file,
> named pipe, or communications device. **In this situation, there is no
> way to know which operation caused the object's state to be signaled.**

The last sentence sounds to me, that the system may wake up my thread erroneously and puts it to sleep again, because *my specific operation* isn't done. This sounds like that the complete system is more efficient, *when* I use a hEvent, even if I don't need it, because I set `bWait` to `TRUE`.

PS: Don't ask me why I use such a way of blocking i/o, it is by design (even it may bad design), so this isn't the question!

PPS: As documented each overlapped i/o in my program uses it's own OVERLAPPED struct.

Comment: of course your code is wrong - dont use `hFile` - when any I/O finished event inside hFile set to signal state . you need or use individual even for any I/O or APC or bind pipe to IOCP

Comment: The point is that if you don't provide hEvent, then the system uses the hFile as the "event". You now have two I/Os using the same completion event, so when you pass `bWait=TRUE`, it will wait for the hFile to be signaled, which happens when *either* I/O completes, and you have no way to know which one.

Comment: I would expect that the threads finally call GetOverlappedResult to get the outcome and return the required result. In detail here: because bWait was TRUE, it will not return until the i/o is done.

Comment: If you know that you have no other code that could cause the file handle to get signaled then you don't have a problem.  That's not hard to know.  At least until an unsuspecting maintainer of the program loses a week of their life some rainy day.

Comment: "because bWait was TRUE, it will not return until the i/o is done." It will not return until *an* I/O on that file is done (since all the I/Os on the file are sharing the same "done" signal). Might not be the one you're waiting for. Suppose that whenever you order a book from a bookstore, your instructions to the delivery person are the same: "When you deliver the book, turn on the porch light." Today, the porch light is on. You know that there is a book, but you don't know *which* book.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I expected a documentation would be more strict and clear about that. As I understood RbMn: When the pipe is bound to an IOCP the hEvent is not required, even if we have concurrent reading and writing (with different OVERLAPPED structs).

Comment: This question would be so much better with a [mcve].

Comment: [`FILE_OBJECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_file_object) have embeded `Event` [`NotificationEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-keinitializeevent). it reset on every I/O begin and set on every I/O end. so use this posible only you have single I/O request (or zero) at any time. use own provided `hEvent` in I/O is 1 of 3 possible variants. with APC and IOCP. how you describe your code, look like APC better for it